# Query S3 from Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am using python to send a query to Athena and get table DDL. I am using `start_query_execution` and `get_query_execution` functions in the awswrangler package.

```
import boto3
import awswrangler as wr
import time
import pandas as pd

boto3.setup_default_session(region_name="us-east-1")

sql="show create table 'table-name'"
query_exec_id = wr.athena.start_query_execution(sql=sql, database='database-name')

time.sleep(20)

res=wr.athena.get_query_execution(query_execution_id=query_exec_id)
```

The code above creates a dict object that stores query results in an s3 link.
The link can be accessed by

`res['ResultConfiguration']['OutputLocation']`. It's a text link: s3://.....txt

Can someone help me figure how to access the output in the link. I tried using readlines() but it seemes to error out.

Here is what I did

```
import urllib3
target_url = res['ResultConfiguration']['OutputLocation']
f = urllib3.urlopen(target_url)
for l in f.readlines():
    print (l)
```

Or if someone can suggest an easier way to get table DDL in python.

Comment: Can you add code which shows how you actually try to read this file? Assuming you have permissions to access the S3 file, you could try with wrangler's S3 methods, maybe `wr.s3.read_csv()`

Comment: yes, I have permissions. I tested with a `select count(*)` and read it with `read_csv()`

Comment: @bzu I tried `wr.s3.read_csv()` as well but that also threw an error

Comment: I have edited to the code to show what I did to read the file

Comment: Alternatively, you could call [`get_query_results()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.get_query_results) rather than `get_query_execution()`. If it gives an error because the query is still running, just make a loop that waits a while and tries again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the returned link will time out after a short while... and make sure your credentials allow you to get the data from the URL specified. If you drop the error message here we can help you better. –

Oh... "It's a text link: s3://.....txt" is not a standard URL. You cant read that with urllib3. You can use awswrangler to read the bucket. –

I think the form is
wr.s3.read_fwf(...)

Comment: The [`awswrangler.s3.read_csv()`](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.s3.read_csv.html#awswrangler.s3.read_csv) documentation says that the `Path` parameter accepts S3 Object paths (`s3://bucket/key`). There are versions for JSON, Excel, Fixed-Width, CSV and Parquet.